# confused with arguments.length in a named arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arguments, arrow-functions

I was trying to get the length of a **named function** using the arguments.length:

```
var a = function(b,c){
console.log(arguments.length);
};
a(1,2); //2 (this is what I'm expecting)


(function(b,c){
console.log(arguments.length);
})(1,2); //it returns 2 also


(b,c) => {
console.log(arguments.length);
};
(1,2); //2 also
```

**but when I tried to use named arrow function:**

```
let a = (b,c) => {
console.log(arguments.length);
};
a(1,2); //ReferenceError: arguments is not defined
```

and this:

```
((b,c) => {
console.log(arguments.length);
})(1,2); //ReferenceError: arguments is not defined
```

I'm really confused now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Arrow functions do not bind the `arguments` magic variable.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_arguments) Your first test is simply wrong; the return value of the expression `(1,2)` is `2`, but only because `2` is the last operand to the `,` operator, not because of `arguments.length`. The "anonymous arrow function" isn't even being invoked in that sample.